# Django custom field or widget?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have an integer fields, but their default widget is TextInput. I want to use Select widget, but I have to explicitly provide possible values.

Is it possible they to be automatically generated from  `'initial', 'min_value' and 'max_value'` validation rules of `integer!` field?

Do I have to make my own field, widget, or both? And how?

Answer (score 2):

You could just do it in the form `__init__` method.

```
def MyForm(forms.Form):
   my_integer = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=10, widget=forms.Select)

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       my_int = self.fields['my_integer']
       my_int.choices = [(i, i) for i in range(my_int.min_value, my_int.max_value)]
```

Comment: Are you sure that my_int.choices = ... is correct place to set values, because to me this didn't work. I only manage to do it using widget=forms.Select(choices = ...)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I generally do special choices:

```
def MyForm(forms.Form):
   INTEGER_CHOICES = [(i, i) for i in range(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE)]
   my_integer = forms.ChoiceField(choices=INTEGER_CHOICES)
```

Rather than introspecting the model field I just put min and max values in a variable at the top for simplicity.

Instead of using an IntegerField, I use a ChoiceField.  Check out the [ChoiceField documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) for details.  They are not difficult to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the field on the form's **init** method, like so:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    initial = 40
    min_value = 10
    max_value = 100

    self.fields['the_field'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=range(min_value, max_value + 1), initial=initial, validators=[MinValueValidator(min_value), MaxValueValidator(max_value)])
```